# How to access another array that is inside an array

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I wonder how can I display the data of "products" that is inside an array please see my code below

**JSON Array**

```
var places = [
{"country_name": "Denmark", "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10, "status": "OK", "site_name": "Denmark", "serial_number": "12345", "products":["1","2"]},
{"country_name": "Japan", "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10, "status": "OK", "site_name": "Norway", "serial_number": "12345", "products":["3","4"]},
{"country_name": "Denmark", "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10, "status": "OK", "site_name": "USA", "serial_number": "12345", "products":["7","6"]}]
```

**Javascript**

```
function displayData(e)
{
var html = '';
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('mapContainer'), i = 0,
    dataIndex, tooltipDiv, key,
    mapMarkers = $(mapDiv).find('.e-mapMarker'), index = 0;
var collection = [];

for (i = 0; i < mapMarkers.length; i++) {

    if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode == mapMarkers[i]) {
        index = i;

    }
}

html += '<div id="infocontainer" class="map_element">';
html += '<div class="p-image"></div>';
html += '<div class="popupdetail">';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Name: ' + places[index].site_name + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Site Status: ' + places[index].status + '</div>';
html += '<div class="p-name"> Country: ' + places[index].country_name + '</div>';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';


if (!document.getElementById('map_tooltip'))
{
    tooltipdiv = $("<div></div>").attr('id', "map_tooltip");
    $(document.body).append(tooltipdiv);
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
        "display": "none", "padding": "5px",
        "position": "absolute",
        "z-index": "13000",
        "cursor": "default",
        "font-family": "Segoe UI",
        "color": "#707070",
        "font-size": "12px", "pointer-events": "none",
        "background-color": "#FFFFFF",
        "border": "1px solid #707070"
    });
}
else
   {
    tooltipdiv = $("#map_tooltip");
    $(tooltipdiv).css({
        "left": (e.pageX + 5),
        "top": (e.pageY + 5)
    });
    $(tooltipdiv).html(html).show("slow");
   }
 }
```

so I want to render the "1","2" that is inside products or if I have multiple countries in array and I want to render a specific product array of a country so I hope I wont get any down vote for not clear english or explanations :-)

Comment: See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: Have you tried places[index].products[0] and places[index].products[1] ?

Comment: at which line do you want to access the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the array like:

```js
var places = [
{"country_name": "Denmark", "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10, "status": "OK", "site_name": "Denmark", "serial_number": "12345", "products":["1","2"]},
{"country_name": "France", "latitude": 5644, "longitude": 1044, "status": "OK", "site_name": "France", "serial_number": "125", "products":["3","4"]}]

places.forEach(function(item, index){
  if(item.country_name == "Denmark"){
    if(item.products){
      item.products.forEach(function(val){
        console.log(val);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: may I ask another question to you? what if I have two countries in the Array (Denmark and France for example) and I want to display only products of Denmark should I replace forEach  by using for loop in order to display the products under Denmark? sorry I very new to this array thing

Comment: Then you need to check the country name like `if(item.country_name=='Denmark'){..`

Comment: @Kyle, I did the changes in the snippet. Please have look.

Comment: ok it works but hate to say that my boss ask me what if I have countries A-Z should I write that if statement equivalent to the numbers of countries in my JSON array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158380/discussion-between-kyle-and-mamun).

Comment: what should I change from your code if I have more than two countries and I want to render/display a specific product array of a country? :-)

Comment: That is what the current code is doing. If you want the product of a specific country you have to check the country else if you want to show all the product form all country just remove the condition.

Answer (score 0):

- `places[0].products[0]` to get value "1"
- `places[0].products[1]` to get value "2"

`places[0].products.join(',')` to join the two values delimited by comma (`,`)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler loop through it seems to me.

```
var places = [
    {"country_name": "Denmark", "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10, "status": 
     "OK", "site_name": "Denmark", "serial_number": "12345", "products":
     ["1","2"]},
    {"country_name": "Denmark", "latitude": 56, "longitude": 10, "status": 
     "OK", "site_name": "Denmark", "serial_number": "12345", "products":
     ["1","2"]}
    ]
for(var j = 0;j<places.length;j++){
   if(places[j].products){
    var plcs = places[j].products
    for(var i = 0;i < plcs.length;i++){
    console.log(plcs[i]);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: will this work if it happens I have more than two countries?

Comment: I mean if I want to display products of a particular country and I have more than two countries?

Comment: Changed for multiple locations. Used same country data for both.  Simpler? you decide.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
places[index].products.join(',')
```

Hope this is what you need.